# How to test a Django app? Downloaded the source code of a Project, how can I open it in Browser?

Tags: python, django

I downloaded a Pinterest-clone project from [Djangosites](http://www.djangosites.org/s/www-wisgoon-com/). Now I want to see it live on my browser.

What changes do I have to make?

Is there everything that is required inside that source folder?

And the size of the directory is only 800KB. Is it always like that?

Is there something missing?

Do I have to install any additional pieces of programs?

A step by step guide would be extremely helpful for a novice like me or you also can provide me the hyperlinks to the sites that already have these steps explained.

I started learning Python just 3 months ago and now diving into Django but I'm already surprised that a Project file can be that small (which has the potential of becoming so big that a whole data-center might one day be required for it.) in size! I understand that it's mostly code(text) and some layout images(Icons, banners, Buttons) and the data(Images, profiles, comments) provided by the users is the reason the site is soon gonna need more space  but kindly offer me some insights about how this works.

Answers to these questions might solve some mysteries that beginners like me face and think Django as magical, miraculous. Well, I think it is but it would be more satisfactory if I can conjure those tricks myself.

Comment: What have you tried? first step is read some documentation and understand the Django framework, you can start from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/ If you want to learn why directly with this project instead of making hello world first.

Comment: @Mutant I am currently studying the The Django Book and can say that I know how to go about creating new projects. But this is a much bigger project and yes, my goal of learning Python/Django is to create awesome things like this. So what harm is there to know how the real things are done? If you think I can't understand what you will say, then TRY ME.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Assume you already have running django project. This is a short way:

1. You need install packages from requirements.txt
2. Instal django-pin (pip install django-pin )
3. add apps as is on installation page (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-pin) in to INSTALLED_APPS in your settings.py
4. adjust your urls.py
5. Start your project python manage.py runserver
6. Navigate your browser to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/pin/`

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but I am facing some issues here. After installing the package using PIP I couldn't find the settings.py.No project folder was created but I could find a folder inside site-packages just exactly where django resides. The way I have learnt is to create a project dirctry. and then an app drctry and then to configure setting.py from within the project folder. Puzzled!!

Comment: Someone please guide about this. On cmd when I install django-pin seems it gets installed inside some temporary folder. And where can I find this requirements.txt?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-pin? They give full instructions there but just to repeat them:

1. Clone repo
2. Install requirements.txt with `pip install -r requirements.txt`
3. Install pip with `pip install django-pin`
4. Add pin to your INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py
5. Add `url(r'pin/', include('pin.urls'))` to your urls.py

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please explain a little further? Don't mind, I am just copy pasting the question I'd asked user2859660 but didn't get any reply. "Pardon my ignorance but I am facing some issues here. After installing the package using PIP I couldn't find the settings.py.No project folder was created but I could find a folder inside site-packages just exactly where django resides. The way I have learnt is to create a project dirctry. and then an app drctry and then to configure setting.py from within the project folder. Puzzled!"

Comment: Yes, the way you have learn is correct. A *project* and an *app* are two different things, and you need a project to put your apps in. Sorry, I Just assumed that you already had one set up.

Comment: Hey Mate,have you run this app on your machine? I donno what I am doing wrong but I couldn't make it work. Here's the screencast. http://imgur.com/oxc6AMy. Where could I possibly be missing something out?